# node server and python client file upload

Tags: python, node.js

Have a scenario in which I am using a python client (requests library) and node server (multer module).

On the Python side -->

```
filepath = "./temp/test.step"
temp = {'file': ('test_file', open(filepath, 'rb'))}
r2 = requests.post('http://localhost:4041/upload', files = temp)
print("File Upload Status: " + r2.text)
```

On the Node side -->

```
var multer  = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest: __dirname + '/uploads/' });
app.post('/upload', upload.single('test_file'), function (req, res ) {
   if (!req.file) {
      return res.sendStatus(400);
   }
   else {
       console.log(req.files);
       return res.sendStatus(200);
   }
})
```

Getting back  --> Error: Unexpected field

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Here is the error that I get on file upload:

```
Error: Unexpected field
at makeError (/PATH2DIR/python_node_upload/node_modules/multer/lib/make-error.js:12:13)
at wrappedFileFilter (/PATH2DIR/python_node_upload/node_modules/multer/index.js:39:19)
at Busboy.<anonymous> (/PATH2DIR/python_node_upload/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:112:7)
at Busboy.emit (events.js:118:17)
at Busboy.emit (/PATH2DIR/python_node_upload/node_modules/multer/node_modules/busboy/lib/main.js:31:35)
at PartStream.<anonymous> (/PATH2DIR/python_node_upload/node_modules/multer/node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:209:13)
at PartStream.emit (events.js:107:17)
at HeaderParser.<anonymous> (/PATH2DIR/python_node_upload/node_modules/multer/node_modules/busboy/node_modules/dicer/lib/Dicer.js:51:16)
at HeaderParser.emit (events.js:107:17)
at HeaderParser._finish (/PATH2DIR/python_node_upload/node_modules/multer/node_modules/busboy/node_modules/dicer/lib/HeaderParser.js:70:8)
```

Comment: Where is this issue coming??

Comment: As soon as I try to upload the file. This is the error that I am getting. Multer is throwing it. See additional edits.